# Sorting dictionary by value

Tags: python

Hi I am using Python to sort my GPS data based on the timestamps and also I would like to add the function of error if the location is same but different timestamp is not possible. I found that my data set is a bit weird. If you can can you suggest new data set type? So far I have this...

```
dic_loc = {'latitude': [],
           'longitude': [],
           'timestamp': []}

def make_timestamped_loc(La, Lng, TS):

    dic_loc['latitude'].append(La)
    dic_loc['longitude'].append(Lng)
    dic_loc['timestamp'].append(int(TS))

make_timestamped_loc(37.481236, 126.952733, 1483196400)
make_timestamped_loc(37.310045, 127.101255, 1408323255)
make_timestamped_loc(37.383065, 126.672596, 1508322531)
make_timestamped_loc(37.383065, 126.672596, 1444999230)

def sort_locs(dictSorting):
    # sortedByTime = sorted(dictSorting.items(), key = lambda i:i[1])
    # print(sortedByTime)
    dictSorting.sort()
    # print(dic_loc)
sort_locs(dic_loc['timestamp'])
print(dic_loc)
```

This code only sort the timestamp values. But I would like my other keys to follow the order of timestamp's value.

Comment: Hyun you are storing the lat, long and ts values in separate `list`s inside a `dict`. That's not a good idea, they are 3 data pieces that need to be together. Instead use either `dict`s, `tuple`s, `collections.namedtuple` or any other container to group these 3 values together and then insert this container into a list. Then you only need to set the `key` parameter of the `sorted()` builtin function to be a function that returns the value you want to use to sort it. The `reversed` parameter allows you to invert the order if you find they are in the opposite order you would expect.

Comment: Where did you get your data from? What is the input?

Comment: @AntonvBR I simply put input like make_timestamped_loc()

Comment: make_timestamped_loc() ?? But what happens next? Does that function return data? If you tell us how you get your data it is much easier to help

Comment: @AntonvBR It is not for returning any data. It is just simply for sorting the data. and printing the data when run it. It is just for practice assignment

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang Ok now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store `lat`, `lon` and `timestamp` in a dict:

```
dic_loc = []

def make_timestamped_loc(La, Lng, TS):
   new_loc = {}
   new_loc['latitude'] = La
   new_loc['longitude'] = Lng
   new_loc['timestamp'] = int(TS)
   dic_loc.append(new_loc)
```

The sorting could be done like this:

```
newlist = sorted(dic_loc, key=lambda k: k['timestamp'])
```

Comment: This method only gives me empty dictionary

Comment: Is this dictionary type?

Comment: Yes, the new_loc is a dictionary and the dic_loc is a list of dictionaries.
Please refer to the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: Hi I am sorry for bothering you but could you help me making making the "newlist = sorted(dic_loc, key=lambda k: k['timestamp'])" into function format??

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for this.

```
from collections import namedtuple
GpsPoint = namedtuple('GpsPoint', ['timestamp', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
points = []
points.append(GpsPoint(1483196400, 37.481236, 126.952733))
points.append(GpsPoint(1408323255, 37.310045, 127.101255))
points.append(GpsPoint(1508322531, 37.383065, 126.672596))
points.append(GpsPoint(1444999230, 37.383065, 126.672596))

print(sorted(points))
```

The attributes of each point are directly accessible:

```
>>> point = GpsPoint(1444999230, 37.383065, 126.672596)
>>> point.timestamp
1444999230
>>> # or by index
>>> point[0]
1444999230
>>> point
GpsPoint(timestamp=1444999230, latitude=37.383065, longitude=126.672596)
```

And it acts like a tuple for sorting so it sorts by the first index (timestamp)

This is a bit of change from having lists of long/lat/time but it forces the points to stay in sync. With the dictionary of lists approach the longitudes can get into a different order to the latitudes so there's no way to get back to the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that does what you ask for:

```
def make_timestamped_loc(La, Lng, TS):
    d = dict(latitude=La,longitude=Lng,timestamp=TS)
    features.append(d)

features = []
make_timestamped_loc(37.481236, 126.952733, 1483196400)
make_timestamped_loc(37.310045, 127.101255, 1408323255)
make_timestamped_loc(37.383065, 126.672596, 1508322531)
make_timestamped_loc(37.383065, 126.672596, 1444999230)
```

---

**or:**

---

```
cols = ['latitude','longitude','timestamp']

features = []

features.append(dict(zip(cols,(37.481236, 126.952733, 1483196400))))
features.append(dict(zip(cols,(37.310045, 127.101255, 1408323255))))
features.append(dict(zip(cols,(37.383065, 126.672596, 1508322531))))
features.append(dict(zip(cols,(37.383065, 126.672596, 1444999230))))
```

---

**then:**

```
sorted(features,key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])
```

Result

```
[{'latitude': 37.310045, 'longitude': 127.101255, 'timestamp': 1408323255},
 {'latitude': 37.383065, 'longitude': 126.672596, 'timestamp': 1444999230},
 {'latitude': 37.481236, 'longitude': 126.952733, 'timestamp': 1483196400},
 {'latitude': 37.383065, 'longitude': 126.672596, 'timestamp': 1508322531}]
```

---

**Different approach:**

But may I suggest you use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text_in_file = u"""37.481236, 126.952733, 1483196400
37.310045, 127.101255, 1408323255
37.383065, 126.672596, 1508322531
37.383065, 126.672596, 1444999230"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_in_file),header=None)
df.columns = ['latitude','longitude','timestamp']
```

---

**or**

---

```
import pandas as pd
import io

cols = ['latitude','longitude','timestamp']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

df.loc[len(df)] = (37.481236, 126.952733, 1483196400)
df.loc[len(df)] = (37.310045, 127.101255, 1408323255)
df.loc[len(df)] = (37.383065, 126.672596, 1508322531)
df.loc[len(df)] = (37.383065, 126.672596, 1444999230)
```

---

**then:**

```
df.sort_values(by="timestamp").to_dict(orient="records")
```

Returns:

```
[{'latitude': 37.310045000000002,
  'longitude': 127.10125499999999,
  'timestamp': 1408323255.0},
 {'latitude': 37.383065000000002,
  'longitude': 126.672596,
  'timestamp': 1444999230.0},
 {'latitude': 37.481236000000003,
  'longitude': 126.95273299999999,
  'timestamp': 1483196400.0},
 {'latitude': 37.383065000000002,
  'longitude': 126.672596,
  'timestamp': 1508322531.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is features  = [] is for?

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang To initiate an empty list which you fill your values to.

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang Very good question. Are you sure you used the sort function correctly?

Comment: oh I have to give new variable I see. But can I make this into function form?

Comment: @HyunMoLukeYang Sorry but that answer really depends on how you want to use the code. I hope my examples above are enough for you to continue :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert this dict into pandas dataframe.

then

sorted = my_dataframe.sort_values(by='timestamp',ascending=False)